# Sublime Text 3 keeps giving drop down menu for semicolon

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to turn this off in sublime text 3? I'm not sure if it is related to a package I've installed; I've tried everything I can think of... Each time I press the semicolon this menu comes up making it extremely inconvenient to have to press Esc for each line.

[image]

Comment: you should just use sass, that way you won't be needing any semicolons anymore :D

Comment: One thing you could do is turn off autocomplete for just CSS, although this probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

it'll be related to one of the packages you have installed. Looks like the semi-colon is a hotkey. You should be able to change the package settings.